# how to use parenthesis or accomplish complex cell rules upon stated logic

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, cell

Setup:

[image]

Logic:

- If a person worked 6 days he needs to rest 2 days otherwise cell O3=1
- Cell O3 is empty if a rule is not violated
- days are up to 31
- those 6 days needs to be in a row followed by 2 days in a row
- point is to check all 26 possible "chunks" of cells

So far I got this:

```
=IF( OR( IF( AND( SUM(B3:G3)=6; SUM(H3:I3)=0); SUM(C3:H3)=6; SUM(I3:J3)=0) ); 1; ); 0; 1;)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You need to explain you rules better. Are 12 days the max in what you look at? Do the six days have to be in a row? Do the two rest days have to be on a row? What are the rules?

Comment: @EdNelson no, days are up to 31. yes 6 days have to be in a row folowing by those 2 days also in a row. point is to check all those "chunks" of possibilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer requires a slight change to you data, but seems to work. It requires replacing the blank cells (non-working days) with zero. The join creates a single string ('1111100111111011111101111110100'). Then the string is searched for occurrences of '11111101'. It counts those occurrences. If count is zero, blank else 'Violation'.

```
=if((LEN(join("",B3:AF3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(join("",B3:AF3),"11111101",)))/LEN("11111101")=0,"","Violation")
```

Copy the formula down.

@Michael has a good point. I added an OR to the above formula with handles both situations. The one above and 7 or more 1s in a row:

```
=if(or((LEN(join("",B3:AF3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(join("",B3:AF3),"1111111",)))/LEN("1111111")>=1,LEN(join("",B3:AF3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(join("",B3:AF3),"11111101",)))/LEN("11111101")=0,"","Violation")
```

Comment: I see. Its a nice idea! Thing is that those "1" are generated via arayformula and I have no idea how to generate those "0". The string I use is `=arrayformula(if((B2:AF2)=1;;if(B2:AF2="";"";(iferror(if(search("5:00";B2:AF2);1);iferror(if(search("13:45";B2:AF2);1);))))))` and if in those cells are 5:00 or 13:45 then "1" is generated otherwise cells are empty. Is there a way how to get those "0" out of my arrayformula?

Comment: I think all you need to do is change the second if to if(B2:AF2="";0;. But I get a parse error with your formula. If this doesn't work could you share your spreadsheet?

Comment: I don't think this solution would identify the violation if someone worked more than 6 days and then had 2 days off, or if they worked 7 days at the end of the period. It should also check for any strings of seven 1's.

Comment: @EdNelson it worked for me like a charm. thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @Michael you've got a good point. but I accidently got it covered with another string:  `=IF(OR(SUM(DD8:DJ8)=7; SUM(DE8:DK8)=7; SUM(DF8:DL8)=7; SUM(DG8:DM8)=7; SUM(DH8:DN8)=7; SUM(DI8:DO8)=7; SUM(DJ8:DP8)=7; SUM(DK8:DQ8)=7; SUM(DL8:DR8)=7; SUM(DM8:DS8)=7; SUM(DN8:DT8)=7; SUM(DO8:DU8)=7; SUM(DP8:DV8)=7; SUM(DQ8:DW8)=7; SUM(DR8:DX8)=7; SUM(DS8:DY8)=7; SUM(DT8:DZ8)=7; SUM(DU8:EA8)=7; SUM(DV8:EB8)=7; SUM(DW8:EC8)=7; SUM(DX8:ED8)=7; SUM(DY8:EE8)=7; SUM(DZ8:EF8)=7; SUM(EA8:EG8)=7; SUM(EB8:EH8)=7); 1;)` which lights up same alert "button" if there is a violation

Comment: @JudgeDredd See the addition to the answer. I am pretty sure I can solve your 0  problem if you can share a sample of your spreadsheet. SO doesn't like these conversations getting too long. If we need to talk more, you can email me at ednelson@sbcglobal.net.